# How to download a xml file using java which is opened in browser?

Tags: java, xml, browser, download, vaadin

I am using  java and vaadin 14 as a framework. I created a xml file. It created successfully and shown in browser. But it cannot be downloaded automatically. I have a code below for creating and downloading that file. Why it doesn't work?

Creating new file code-

```java
//Creating a xml file
String xmlOutPath,fname;
Random r = new Random();
fname =   r.nextInt(1000000)+".xml"
File file = File.createTempFile("a-", fname, new File(xmlOutPath));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

This file successfully created. Then i have a code to download it-

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.UI;
//download xml file
 File downloadFile;
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
transformer.transform(source, result);
fos.close();
downloadFile = file;
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("location.href = \"./rpttmp/" + downloadFile.getName() + ";\"");
```

But i found like this-
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml

How can this file automatically downloaded, rather showing that file on browser?

Comment: Take a look at this thread on a Vaadin Forum: [Vaadin 10 autmoatically download a file without clicking a button](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17360172/vaadin-10-autmoatically-download-a-file-without-clicking-a-button). There is a similar discussion there with a code example

Comment: I am using vaadin 14.

Comment: There is no difference in that respect between V10 and V14 :) So the suggestions there are still valid